# Entity Framework data migration with custom logic?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Suppose, I want to replace table `A` with table `B` and migrate all data from one to another, so I do:

1. Create table `B` through **SQL query**
2. Perform transformation over entire copy of data from `A` format to `B` format through **SQL query**
3. Put everything to `B` table through **SQL query**
4. Delete table `A` through **SQL query**

The problem is, sometimes you need to break transaction and do non-transactional transform from `A` format to `B` format, which can even involve calls to different services (for example, new geo-political status of object from `A`, or different serialization contract of fields from `A`, 7zip it from `A` to `B` or whatever you desire to change about data in `A`).

So, the question is, how to accomplish **step 2** through EF in **any desirable way**:

2. Perform transformation over entire copy of data from `A` format to `B` format through **"black box"**

By that I mean not breaking concept of EF migration files, and providing me with something like "Main" method as entry point for my migration step. Any suggestions?

Comment: Running the custom SQL should be no problem using `MigrationBuilder.Sql()`. Not sure how you can get a proxy to the webservices into the migration though. See also [Custom Migrations Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations#using-migrationbuildersql)

Comment: No, this is not what Im looking. By custom here I mean really custom, like invoking Python/C++/C/C# library or making some other integration for transformation of data.

Comment: Sorry never done that :(

Comment: As far as I can see, you could open a separate database connection inside the Up method (not an EF context, but some more or less plain old connection), query data from A, process them and generate SQL insert statements for B that are included into the Migration via `Sql` method. Downside: you need a database downtime without external changes from the moment of Update-Database until the migration is fully applied - so pre-generating the migration SQL and executing it later is not a valid option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible with Entity Framework. Every operation that is available in migrations is transformed to SQL operations that are later invoked. (By operating this way EF allows you to script whole migration process to SQL file and run it in e.g. SQL Server Management Studio).

Because SQL generation is separated from invoking it, it's not possible to execute custom C#/Python/anything non-SQL.

As migrations allows only features provided by SQL Server (or different DB if supported) you can use features like CLR Assemblies or `xp_cmdshell` which are not the most straightforward things to use but that way it is possible to execute almost any migration code

Comment: Actually, this is pretty good solution because cmd forces you to fix binaries like you fix SQL query in your migrations. Well, it can be pretty handy if one can write something like "precompiler" extension, which will be asociated with migration and invoked through "xp_cmdshell". Might actually write it.

Comment: @eocron If you do, let us know - it will be useful :)